# Attempting to set up dual boot - Windows not detected by Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I am attempting to set up dual boot on my computer. It is currently running Windows 10, and I am trying to add Ubuntu 22.04. In Ubuntu's tutorial for installing Ubuntu ([link](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#6-type-of-installation)) they indicate that Ubuntu will automatically detect Windows Boot Manager, and give you the option to set up dual boot. However, when I reach that page in the installation process, the installation manager says "This computer currently has no detected operating systems".

I have looked around and found several tutorials ([example](https://www.techsupportpk.com/2020/04/how-to-fix-ubuntu-not-detecting-windows.html)) suggesting that fixing errors in Windows C: partition with chkdsk will do the trick, but it has not worked for me. Each time I boot my computer with the installation media (USB stick) in, the installation manager fails to detect Windows. I know Windows is there, because when I boot my computer without the installation media, it boots to Windows and everything runs fine.

I also found [this article](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2021/12/grub-doesnt-detect-windows-linux-distros-fix) claiming that grub in Ubuntu 22.04 does not scan for other operating systems anymore. However, I cannot test the solution they gave, as I am just trying to set up dual-boot and am stuck in Windows, whereas they are repairing a previous dual-boot system, and have access to Ubuntu.

Does anybody know what is going on here, and how I might fix it? Is it indeed the case that Ubuntu 22.04 does not work to set up new dual boot systems right now? Should I just try Ubuntu 23.04?

Update: [Image of my manual partitioning options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrGYY.jpg)

Comment: Where are you planning on installing Ubuntu? It looks like there are three partitions on your drive. The first is the EFI boot loader, the 2nd is 16mb and too small for anything, and the third is almost 500gb, which is probably where your Windows install is. So at the moment you don’t have anywhere to install Ubuntu. Is there a second drive that we’re not seeing? If not, then you’ll first need to free up some space to make a new partition to install Ubuntu on.

Comment: `/dev/sda3` use 79 gb from 499 gb so you can resize it to make new partition

Comment: to know how resize the partition safely  https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/resize-linux-partition-safely/

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have successfully installed Ubuntu Linux alongside Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

you can choose the last one from the choices manual partitioning or other option
[image]

you will see all of your partition, dont edit any windows partition, install ubuntu in another partition. after finishing and reboot you will find windows in the boot menu, if not you can use bios options or  enable os prober or boot-repair tool.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I have never done this before. How do I know which of the listed partitions Windows is occupying/using? And once I have determined that, can I simply install Ubuntu into any other partition, or are there other partitions I should avoid?

Comment: @inept_python you will see details beside all partitions, manually windows take the 1st 2 partitions. update your question by image about this step to show the partitions.

Comment: I have updated my post with an image of my manual partitioning options. Do you have a link to a good tutorial on how to go about this? I don't really feel comfortable guessing, and I don't necessarily want to keep bothering you with trivial questions.